# Confusion about logical type in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, logical-operators

Can we compare logical to numeric type (double) in MATLAB?
Why 0 <= 0.1 <= 0.2 returns 0 and 0 <= 2 <= 4 returns 1?

Comment: In addition to @GiacomoPirinoli's answer, it is interesting to read [the documentation about `operator precedence`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html). The operators `<`,`>`,`<=`,`>=`,`==` and `~=` are at the same level, so they are intepreted from left to right. You can write your comparison like this: `(0 <= 0.1) && (0.1 <= 0.2)`. Noticed that the parenthesis are not mandatory but (from the doc): *It is a good idea to use parentheses to explicitly specify the intended precedence of statements containing*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not read 0 <= 0.1 <= 0.2 and 0 <= 2 <= 4 in a *mathematical way* but in a *programming way*.

Considering a cast like `true<-->1` and `false<-->0`,
I mean:

- 0<=0.1<=0.2
- 1<=0.2 (because 0<=0.1 is true)
- 0 (because 1<=0.2 is false)

similarly:

- 0<=2<=4
- 1<=4 (because 0<=2 is true)
- 1 (because 1<=4 is true)